# Curl encoding issues with command line

Tags: curl, command-line

When i try to download the content of websites with special characters like ï, curl returns strange characters. For example when i execute the following from the command line:

```
curl.exe --GET "http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ge%C3%AFnteresseerd"
```

the (partial) response is:

```
...wgPageName":"geÃ¯nteresseerd","wgTitle":"geÃ¯nteresseerd",....
```

the problem is Ã¯ should be ï. Is there anyway to solve this issue? Do i need to re-encode the response?

Comment: This is due to handling of unicode characters in a DOS prompt, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Comment: @HansZ. Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: alrighty, added it as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to handling of unicode characters in a DOS prompt, see [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how). You should be able to change this behavior by using a command like `chcp 65001` to set the terminal up for UTF-8 handling.